# ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve

Tags: linux, centos, yum, package-management, packages

```
Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================================
Install       9 Package(s)
Upgrade     227 Package(s)
Remove        1 Package(s)

Total size: 252 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libasound.so.2()(64bit) is needed by libgcj-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit) is needed by libgcj-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
** Found 15 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
alsa-lib-devel-1.0.22-3.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of alsa-lib = ('0', '1.0.22', '3.el6')
alsa-lib-devel-1.0.22-3.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2()(64bit)
alsa-utils-1.0.22-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2()(64bit)
alsa-utils-1.0.22-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit)
alsa-utils-1.0.22-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)(64bit)
alsa-utils-1.0.22-5.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc8)(64bit)
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-2.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2()(64bit)
gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-2.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit)
gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-2.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)(64bit)
libgcj-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2()(64bit)
libgcj-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit)
1:qt-x11-4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2()(64bit)
1:qt-x11-4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit)
1:qt-x11-4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64 has missing requires of libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)(64bit)
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2013-12-23-22-364infzT.yumtx
root@www1 [~]#
```

I did some research and this is due to a 32bit binary trying to install itself or broken repo?

```
root@www1 [~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * updates: ftp.usf.edu
repo id                                              repo name                                                                                    status
base                                                 CentOS-6 - Base                                                                              6,284+83
dag                                                  Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux                                              4,559+91
extras                                               CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                  14
updates                                              CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                             247+39
repolist: 11,104
```

Now I disabled epel and rpmforge repops and still ended up with the same issues. Ideas?

Comment: Your system is infected with cPanel. It wouldn't surprise me at all if cPanel broke it. First thing I would do (if getting rid of cPanel isn't an option) is to contact their support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the latest atrpms-repo:

```
wget http://dl.atrpms.net/el6-x86_64/atrpms/stable/atrpms-repo-6-7.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh atrpms-repo-6-7.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum clean all
```

Then, install the libasound2 package:

```
yum --enablerepo=atrpms-testing install libasound2
yum update
```